# Amazon ECS Container HealthCheck

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, health-monitoring

I am updating the task definition of an ECS container. I want it to run a healthcheck before hand which I did as follows in the docker file JSON.

```
      "healthCheck": {
        "command": ["CMD-SHELL", "exit 1"],
        "interval": 300,
        "timeout": 60,
        "retries": 1,
        "startPeriod": 150
      }
```

I just want it to fail to deploy to the container. However, it still exits successfully. This is so confusing. I am at a loss for what else to try here. Please ignore the numbers -- was trying various configurations.

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind interval 300, timeout 60, retries 1 and startperiod 150.
The command is perfect for a failure though.

Comment: @GSSwain Nothing was just trying various configurations -- no configuration seems to get it to fail though.